# Query to calculate data +/- 4 weeks from a specific date

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-workbench

I have to calculate for a specific date (creation date) the sales 4 weeks before and 4 weeks after (the data a need to calculate is for each week)

My blocker is to calculate the item list 4 weeks before week by week and the same for weeks after.So I have to do this query 8 times changing the date

```
SELECT
    product,
    SUM(sales)
FROM
    Sales_table
WHERE
    DATA <= date - 1
AND product IN (
    product1,
    product2,
    ...., 
    product10000
);
```

I have to do it for **date-1, date-2..., date-4** and then **date+1,...,date+4** (sometimes I have to do it for +/- 12 weeks) and do the same thing for views_table so it's like **48 queries** for **10K** products and it copuld generate bug in workbench. There exits any other way to do this? with TMP tables for example, and how could I write the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used your query like this (below). The Tables I use are **P_Master** and **P_Master_Cat** (*I can use the first one as all information exists on it*). When I run the Query I have the following issue "**Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function**"

```
SELECT p.sku_conf  AS product
 , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -4 WEEK AND t.date < i.dt + INTERVAL -3 WEEK,t.ItemID,NULL)),0) AS `d-4`
 , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -3 WEEK AND t.date < i.dt + INTERVAL -2 WEEK,t.ItemID,NULL)),0) AS `d-3`
 , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -2 WEEK AND t.date < i.dt + INTERVAL -1 WEEK,t.ItemID,NULL)),0) AS `d-2`
 , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -1 WEEK AND t.date < i.dt + INTERVAL  0 WEEK,t.ItemID,NULL)),0) AS `d-1`
 , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL  0 WEEK AND t.date < i.dt + INTERVAL  1 WEEK,t.ItemID,NULL)),0) AS `d+0`
 , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL  1 WEEK AND t.date < i.dt + INTERVAL  2 WEEK,t.ItemID,NULL)),0) AS `d+1`
FROM ( SELECT '2016-01-06' AS dt ) i
JOIN P_Master_Cat p
  ON p.sku_conf IN 
  ('OE599EL9',
  'OE599EL86',
  'OE599EL90',
  'OE599EL75')
LEFT JOIN P_Master t
  ON t.SKUConf = p.sku_conf
  AND t.date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -6 WEEK
  AND t.date <  i.dt + INTERVAL  6 WEEK
GROUP BY p.sku_conf
```

Comment: I don't think you want to sum **`ItemID`**.  The original question shows `SUM(sales)`. The expression `sku_config` appears only in the GROUP BY clause. Other references are `sku_conf`... we can only guess at what the *actual* columns in your tables are.

Comment: I had a mistake in my original query...   should be a plus and not a minus...  **`+ INTERVAL -6 WEEK`**.  (or could be `- INTERVAL 6 WEEK`.  (Subtracting a negative is the same as adding a positive.)

Comment: I edited the details. It works.I have a doubt, I use `**Count(ItemID)**` to know Sold total item number. and Item will only display 1 (I think). How could I do that? and How could I add `**SUM(Revenue)**` for each product per week?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.id   AS product
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -4 WEEK AND t.creation_date < i.dt + INTERVAL -3 WEEK,t.sales,NULL)),0) AS `d-4`
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -3 WEEK AND t.creation_date < i.dt + INTERVAL -2 WEEK,t.sales,NULL)),0) AS `d-3`
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -2 WEEK AND t.creation_date < i.dt + INTERVAL -1 WEEK,t.sales,NULL)),0) AS `d-2`
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -1 WEEK AND t.creation_date < i.dt + INTERVAL  0 WEEK,t.sales,NULL)),0) AS `d-1`
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL  0 WEEK AND t.creation_date < i.dt + INTERVAL  1 WEEK,t.sales,NULL)),0) AS `d+0`
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL  1 WEEK AND t.creation_date < i.dt + INTERVAL  2 WEEK,t.sales,NULL)),0) AS `d+1`
  FROM ( SELECT '2016-04-01' AS dt ) i
  JOIN products p
    ON p.id IN 
       ( product1
       , product2
       , ...
       , product10000
       )
  LEFT
  JOIN Sales_table t
    ON t.product_id = p.id
   AND t.creation_date >= i.dt + INTERVAL -6 WEEK
   AND t.creation_date <  i.dt + INTERVAL  6 WEEK
 GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Thanks it's work for some products but when it a huge list my workbench goes down.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what behavior "my workbench goes down" describes. I suggest you use EXPLAIN to see the query execution plan. And I suggest you test the query from the mysql command line client. If there's an issue with the query  (It's not clear what issue you are encountering) you might consider running the query with a smaller set in the IN list. Or even running the query with one product id at a time. It's not possible to suggest a fix for the problem, without knowing what the actual problem is.

Comment: My workbench generate the error connection timed out , maybe my queries aren't optimales or the listing I need to extract is huge.please thequery generate error "Invalid group of use" . I've tried to correct it but the issue remains. I have products and sales in the same table. What is the "where" role in the Query?

Comment: The `WHERE` keyword should be removed, I failed to remove that when I relocated the predicate on the product.id column to the `ON` clause.  Use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan. You'd definitely want an index `on sales_table (product_id, creation_date, sales)`. There are a couple of other SQL statements (different forms) that would return an equivalent result. Personally, I would limit the size of the `IN` list. I'd test with just a single value.

Comment: Using Explain the action displayed is only "OK"

Answer (score 0):

Just use a self join to get the results here

```
select t.date,sum(t1.sales) 
 from Sales_table t join Sales_table t1 on
  t1.date between date_add(t.date, interval -4 week) and
     date_add(t.date, internal 4 week)
```

use this query to get sum of sales from before and after four weeks

If you want the details for specific products use the below query(for product wise sum)

```
select t.date,sum(t1.sales) 
 from Sales_table t join Sales_table t1 on
  t.product=t1.product and
  t1.date between date_add(t.date, interval -4 week) and
     date_add(t.date, internal 4 week)
```